# Swift: What's the best way to pair up elements of an Array

Tags: arrays, swift, functional-programming, immutability

I came across a problem that required iterating over an array in pairs. What's the best way to do this? Or, as an alternative, what's the best way of transforming an Array into an Array of pairs (which could then be iterated normally)?

Here's the best I got. It requires `output` to be a `var`, and it's not really pretty. Is there a better way?

```
let input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

var output = [(Int, Int)]()

for i in stride(from: 0, to: input.count - 1, by: 2) {
    output.append((input[i], input[i+1]))
}


print(output) // [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]

// let desiredOutput = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
// print(desiredOutput)
```

Comment: What if your array number of elements it is not even? The last element will always be discarded.

Comment: It's safe to assume there are an even number of elements. If not, handle it however you wish (throw, fatal error, ignore the singleton, etc.(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is now available as

[`Sequence.chunks(ofCount: 2)`](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Chunked.md) of the [`swift-algorithms` package](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms)

```
for chunk in input.chunks(ofCount: 2) {
    print(chunk)
}
```

Comment: Not sure what is the relation of adjacent pairs with your question which originally was getting every two elements `[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]`. Btw are you sure `chunks(ofCount:)` returns adjacent pairs as well `[[1, 2],[2, 3],[3, 4],[4, 5]]`?

Comment: Oh true, I got mixed up. reverting.

Answer (score 35):

You can *map* the stride instead of iterating it, that 
allows to get the result as a *constant:*

```
let input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

let output = stride(from: 0, to: input.count - 1, by: 2).map {
    (input[$0], input[$0+1])
}

print(output) // [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

If you only need to iterate over the pairs and the given array is large
then it may be advantageous to avoid the creation of an intermediate
array with a lazy mapping:

```
for (left, right) in stride(from: 0, to: input.count - 1, by: 2)
    .lazy
    .map( { (input[$0], input[$0+1]) } ) {

    print(left, right)

}
```

Comment: Beauty! I'll wait a bit before accepting this, I want to see what else comes up

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov: Sure! – I assume your question is motivated by http://stackoverflow.com/a/40841493/1187415?

Comment: Not quite, I've had this come a few times in the past, and that question was the straw that broke the camel's back. I don't want to be teaching shitty swift if I can help it :p

Comment: @MartinR The first code snippet is so logical to me, but after you edited your answer, actually, I didn't got it for the second one, what's the purpose of using the `lazy`? Yes, I knew that the output is `LazyRandomAccessCollection<Self>`, but it still a little confusing to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AhmadF: `map` on a Collection returns an *array* with all mapped elements, before you even start iterating. `lazy`  creates a "lazy sequence" on which the `map` method is implemented lazily: Each element is fetched and mapped "on demand", when requested during the iteration. That is more expensive but saves memory.

Comment: @MartinR How does the computational overhead of the bookkeeping for lazy evaluation compare with the memory hit of eager evaluation? Obviously you should judge for yourself by profiling the issue when it comes up, but which approach would you opt for by default?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov: Start with the simple solution #1. If it becomes an performance problem, try the lazy solution #2. It depends on the array size *and* on the complexity of the map function. In this case I would *guess* that #1 is faster at least for arrays of some hundred elements. But I did not measure it, that is a pure guess.

Comment: @MartinR My only issue is that I would like a "best guess" for what's best in most typical cases, for which constantly profiling and micro optimizing isn't practical.

Comment: What's the SO etiquette on updating a question like this? There's now a first party solution to this question, and I want to point people to it rather than this hand-rolled version. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68187239/3141234

Comment: @Alexander: The *question* does not change, does it? But of course you are free to accept your *answer* instead.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is any better than Martin R's, but seems the OP needs something else...

```
struct PairIterator<C: IteratorProtocol>: IteratorProtocol {
    private var baseIterator: C
    init(_ iterator: C) {
        baseIterator = iterator
    }

    mutating func next() -> (C.Element, C.Element)? {
        if let left = baseIterator.next(), let right = baseIterator.next() {
            return (left, right)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
extension Sequence {
    var pairs: AnySequence<(Self.Iterator.Element,Self.Iterator.Element)> {
        return AnySequence({PairIterator(self.makeIterator())})
    }
}

input.pairs.forEach{ print($0) }

let output = input.pairs.map{$0}
print(output) //->[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

Comment: Minor suggestions (surely a matter of personal preferences): `Array(input.pairs)` instead of `...map{$0}`, `Self.` can be omitted in `Self.Iterator.Element`. – A special thank you for *not* using `guard` in the next method :)

Comment: @MartinR Could you explain what's wrong with using `guard` in the `next` method?

Comment: MartinR's solution worked just fine, I just wanted to see what else people come up with before I accept his answer. This solution was another one I was considering. Thanks for implementing it :)

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov: I am not a fan of *always* using guard for an early return. That is a matter of personal taste, don't take my remark too seriously. Here is a recent example where (I think) a if/else if/else would be easier to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835332/how-does-this-function-calculate.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, that exact same question actually made me rethink my stance on guard.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a version of @OOPer's answer that works with an odd number of elements in your list. You can leave off the conformance to `CustomStringConvertible` if you like, of course. But it gives prettier output for this example. : )

```
struct Pair<P: CustomStringConvertible>: CustomStringConvertible {
    let left: P
    let right: P?

    var description: String {
        if let right = right {
            return "(\(left.description), \(right.description)"
        }
        return "(\(left.description), nil)"
    }
}

struct PairIterator<C: IteratorProtocol>: IteratorProtocol where C.Element: CustomStringConvertible {
    private var baseIterator: C
    init(_ iterator: C) {
        baseIterator = iterator
    }

    mutating func next() -> Pair<C.Element>? {
        if let left = baseIterator.next() {
            return Pair(left: left, right: baseIterator.next())
        }
        return nil
    }
}
extension Sequence where Element: CustomStringConvertible {
    var pairs: AnySequence<Pair<Self.Element>> {
        return AnySequence({PairIterator(self.makeIterator())})
    }
}

let input: [Int] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
print(input.pairs)
print(Array(input.pairs))


//output:
AnySequence<Pair<Int>>(_box: Swift._SequenceBox<Swift._ClosureBasedSequence<__lldb_expr_27.PairIterator<Swift.IndexingIterator<Swift.Array<Swift.Int>>>>>)
[(1, 2, (3, 4, (5, 6, (7, nil)]
```

Comment: Now that we have conditional conformances, you should move the conformance of `CustomStringConvertible` to be conditional

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a custom type, like `PairIterator` as the above answers prescribe. Getting a paired sequence is a one-liner:

```
let xs = [1, 2, 3]
for pair in zip(xs, xs.dropFirst()) {
    print(pair) // (1, 2) (2, 3)
}
```

If you intend to reuse that, you can place a pairs method inside an extension:

```
extension Sequence {
    func pairs() -> AnySequence<(Element, Element)> {
        AnySequence(zip(self, self.dropFirst()))
    }
}
```

Comment: `PairIterator` could be useful if you do this a lot, although the name is ambigious because it doesn't describe how the pairing is done. One way is the one you showed, which is useful for putting fence posts between fence segments. The way I was asking about in the question is different, the expected output was `[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]` such as for presenting a 2x3 grid of items from an array.