# Iterate through an array to find pairs of values

Tags: swift

I have a sorted array.  I would like to iterate through the array and increment a counter as I find pairs of values.  I'm not finding an elegant solution to this.

```
var pairs = 0
    let colors = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20
    let sortedColors = colors.sorted{ $0 < $1}
    // [10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30, 50] -> pairs should equal 3

    for i in 0..<colors.count - 1 {
        if sortedColors[i+1] != colors.count && sortedColors[i] == sortedColors[i+1] {
            pairs += 1
        } 
    }

print(pairs)
```

Comment: When you say "pairs" do you mean values that occur more than once? Can you define what a "pair of values" is. It's hard to tell from your question. :)

Comment: values that occur twice.  [10,10,10,10]  would be two pairs.  pairs == 2

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was a bit quick to dupe-mark this one. Should I re-open?

Comment: Surely that should be three pairs? (0, 1) (1, 2) (2, 3) are all pairs? OK... in the array [1, 2, 2, 3] is that 1 pair or 0?

Comment: @dfri I think so :)

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40841663/swift-whats-the-best-way-to-pair-up-elements-of-an-array

Comment: @Fogmeister.  Sorry I'm not clear.  in your array.. [1,2,2,3] that is one pair of matching numbers.  One pair of twos.

Comment: So Martin, in your example, the **3** pairs are `(10, 10)`, `(10, 10)` and `(20, 20)`?

Comment: No worries :D Just trying to work out why the middle two tens [10, (10, 10), 10] in your array is not counted as a pair :) So a pair is any number followed by the same number but the second number is then excluded from the check for the third?

Comment: Yes.  So [2,2,2,1] only contains one pair.  Index 0 and index 1 match up.  Index 2 would have no match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative but similar approach as [@Sulthan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49261787/4573247) is to use a dictionary to count occurrences rather than `NSCountedSet`:

```
let colors = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20]
let numberOfPairs = colors
  .reduce(into: [:]) { counts, num in counts[num, default: 0] += 1 }
  .reduce(0) { cumsum, kv in cumsum + kv.value / 2 } // 3
```

Or, using shorthand argument names in the two closures:

```
let numberOfPairs = colors
  .reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1, default: 0] += 1 }
  .reduce(0) { $0 + $1.value / 2 }
```

Where above, for the number occurrence count, we make use of [@vacawama's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30545629/4573247) in the Q&A that I initially used as target for dupe-marking this Q&A.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'm glad I asked.  I've been studying map, reduce, and filter... still got a long way to go.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You could as well use  new Dictionary syntax like so,

With grouping syntax,

```
let pairs = Dictionary(grouping: colors){ $0 }
                        .map { $1.count / 2 }
                        .reduce(0, +)
print(pairs)
```

With  uniquing syntax,

```
let pairs = Dictionary( zip( colors, Array(repeating: 1, count: colors.count)),
                       uniquingKeysWith: +)
                      .reduce(0, { $0 + $1.1 / 2})
```

Comment: Beauty. Nicest answer here, IMO.

Comment: @Alexander It does look beautiful indeed. Thanks !

Comment: @Alexander I did it now with  uniquing syntax as well :)

Comment: `Array(repeating: 1, count: colors.count)` could just be `[colors.count]`

Comment: I don't get how the second example works, it seems quite unclear

Comment: @Alexander I also agree that this is neat, but it should be noted that it might not be as efficient as the other two answers, as it unnecessarily creates a number of arrays (the values of the `Dictionary`; e.g. `[50: [50], 10: [10, 10, 10, 10], 20: [20, 20, 20], 30: [30]]`) all having the same member repeated a number of times, where the sole information used in these same-element arrays is their count. Nice nonetheless with an alternative approach to the "frequency counting" ones of the other answer! The second approach above (although not as neat) is kind of clever though.

Comment: Well, I agree that this might not be efficient as others. But, code looks neat and a bit more swifty to say :)

Comment: @dfri Yeah, I wish there was a `lazy` variant of grouping, or perhaps one that lets you instantly `mapValues` inplace

Comment: First one, a bit tighter: `let pairs = Dictionary(grouping: colors){ $0 }.map { $1.count / 2 }.reduce(0, +)`

Comment: @vacawama I wanted to write exactly the same! A single `Dictioary.reduce` call could be used but I like it better this way. Or just a `map` over `.values`.

Answer (score 2):

I would just count the repetitions and then divide the number of repetitions by 2 to count the pairs. For example, if a number appears 3 times, there is one pair:

```
let colors = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20]

let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: colors)
let pairs = countedSet.map { countedSet.count(for: $0) / 2 }.reduce(0, +)
print(pairs) // 3
```

Unfortunately, there is no Swift `CountedSet` yet :(

Comment: In your array there are only 2 pairs. 20, 20 and 10, 10.

Comment: @Fogmeister There are two "10" pairs

Comment: Not by the rules of the OP :) Only adjacent equivalent values count as a pair.

Comment: @Fogmeister There is a comment that says `[10, 10, 10, 10]` are two pairs :)

Comment: Yes. `array[0, 1]` and `array[2, 3]`. In your example the only pairs are `colors[1, 2]` and `colors[3, 4]`. `colors[0]` and `colors[3]` are not a pair.

Comment: @Fogmeister Note that I have skipped the sorting because I don't need it, therefore I don't have to care which pairs are adjacent.

Comment: @Fogmeister, OP is sorting the array before looking for pairs

Comment: I got that solution too, but used directly map on `countedSet` and didn't use `allObjects` in between. Just wondering since I'm not a Swift developer the benefits or potential issues.

Comment: @Larme I just didn't realize that I can use `map` directly.

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks for the information. I was wondering if it was just a Playground "allowed" stuff, CocoaTouch/Cocoa difference because I tend to use directly suggestions/autocomplete from XCode to find methods in Swift.

Comment: @Sulthan Please check my answer, I attempted to use Dictionary grouping syntax and I think this would work.