# Swift Comparison in consecutive numbers inside array and its count

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

How can I compare the two consecutive numbers in an array and find its count.

```
let numberArray = [1,2,4,6,7,10,12,13]
// I want to compare two consecutive numbers like [1,2], [4,6], [7,10], [12,13]
```

For example: 
First, I want to calculate difference of the first two numbers[1,2(difference=1)]in the array, then the next two numbers[4,6(difference=2)], then[7,10(difference=3)] and [12,13(difference=1)] at last.
Lastly, I want to count a number of difference that has 1. In this case the count is 2.

What method should I use for this one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40841806/2395636) by [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r), you can check how to create pairs as below,

```
let input = [1,2,4,6,7,10,12,13]
let output = stride(from: 0, to: input.count - 1, by: 2).map{(input[$0], input[$0 + 1])}
```

Now you can create differences array and find the one's count as below,

```
let differences = output.map({ $0.1 - $0.0 })
let onesCount = differences.filter({ $0 == 1}).count

print(differences)
print(onesCount)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 1]
2
```

Comment: hi, thanks. this worked like a charm! this one is very simple and easy to follow

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are nicer ways to do this (but it's Monday morning).
One easy solution is to loop through the array using a stride, allowing you to take steps off two.
You then append each difference to a new difference array.
And finally use a filter on this resulting array to determine how often that difference occurs.

```
let difference      = 1
let array           = [1,2,4,6,7,10,12,13]
var differenceArray = [Int]()
for index in stride(from: 1, to: array.count, by: 2) {
    let difference  = array[index]-array[index-1]
    differenceArray.append(difference)
}

print(differenceArray.filter{ $0 == difference }.count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Good answer by @Philip. Here is an updated solution also handled other cases.

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 5, 4, 10, 6, 7, 8, 11, 10, 23]
var allDifference: [Int] = []
for index in stride(from: 0, to: numbers.count, by: 2) {
   let firstValue = numbers[index]
   let secondValue = ((index == numbers.count - 1 && numbers.count % 2 != 0) ? 0 : numbers[index + 1])
   allDifference.append(abs(firstValue - secondValue))
}

let oneDifferenceCount = allDifference.filter { $0 == 1 }.count
print("Result: ", oneDifferenceCount)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a 2 lines of code using `zip` `compactMap` and `reduce`:

First we create a tuple of consecutive elements, we use `zip` in order to use the index of the element and `compactMap` to filter `nil` elements then we reduce the new array to count only the tuples with a difference of 1

```
//Create tuples of consecutive values
let tuples = zip(numberArray.indices, numberArray).compactMap{$0 % 2 == 0 ? nil : (numberArray[$0-1],$1) }
// reduce to count only the tuples with difference of 1
let diffOneCount = tuples.reduce(0,{$1.0+1 == $1.1 ? $0+1 : $0})
```