# Creating a dictionary from an array

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have an array of items ["1", "2", "3", "4"] and I want to be create a dictionary to look like the following:

let dictionary = ["1": "2", "3" : "4"]

Comment: Did you try anything? What happen if you have an odd count item in your array? Are you looking on how to iterate by n? (`stride()`)?

Comment: I would use some of the code in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40841663/3141234) to turn the input into `[(1, 2), (3, 4)]`, and then just pass that on to `Dictionary.init(uniqueKeysWithValues)` to make it into a dict.

Comment: @Sara Did these comments/links answer your question, or should I reopen it?

Comment: Yes they did, thank you!