# How to change data in array of Structure?

Tags: ios, swift, struct

my code is like below,

```
struct RegistrationInformation {
    let leftTitle: String
    let rightTitle: String

}

struct RegisterData{
    let vValueL : String
}
var regDatas : [RegistrationInformation] = []

       for i in 0...3 {
            regDatas.append(RegistrationInformation(leftTitle: regData[i].vValue, rightTitle: ""))
        }
        for i in 4...7 {
            regDatas.append(RegistrationInformation(leftTitle: "", rightTitle: regData[i].vValue))
        }

//output of regDatas is 

       [Datas.RegistrationInformation(leftTitle: "line 1", rightTitle: ""),
        Datas.RegistrationInformation(leftTitle: "line3", rightTitle: ""),
        Datas.RegistrationInformation(leftTitle: "line5", rightTitle: ""),
        Datas.RegistrationInformation(leftTitle: "line7", rightTitle: ""),
        Datas.RegistrationInformation(leftTitle: "", rightTitle: "line2"),
        Datas.RegistrationInformation(leftTitle: "", rightTitle: "line4"),
        Datas.RegistrationInformation(leftTitle: "", rightTitle: "line6"),
        Datas.RegistrationInformation(leftTitle: "", rightTitle: "line8")]
```

what I want is like below in regDatas

```
  [Datas.RegistrationInformation(leftTitle: "line 1", rightTitle: "line2"),
        Datas.RegistrationInformation(leftTitle: "line3", rightTitle: "line4"),
        Datas.RegistrationInformation(leftTitle: "line5", rightTitle: "line6"),
        Datas.RegistrationInformation(leftTitle: "line7", rightTitle: "line8")]
```

I want to change data position in array struct of regDatas.
how can we do that
thank you

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40841663/3141234 Iterate over one of those sequences, and you'll have access to pairs of numbers you can use to fill your registration information

Comment: @Alexander 
I have used below code from your link

```
for (left, right) in stride(from: 0, to: input.count - 1, by: 2)
    .lazy
    .map( { (input[$0], input[$0+1]) } ) {

    print(left, right)

}

```
how can I store left and right to the RegistrationInformation's left title and right title respectively?

Comment: Similar to the way you do it now: You have `regDatas.append(RegistrationInformation(leftTitle: "line\(left)", rightTitle: "line\(right)"))`. Your fundamental issue is that you're making twice as many instances as you need, and each of them has one of their two fields `""`, which is not at all what you want

Answer (score 1):

```
struct RegistrationInformation {

    let leftTitle: String
    let rightTitle: String

}


struct RegisterData{

    let vValueL : String

}


var regData: [RegisterData] = [
    RegisterData(vValueL: "line1"),
    RegisterData(vValueL: "line2"),
    RegisterData(vValueL: "line3"),
    RegisterData(vValueL: "line4"),
    RegisterData(vValueL: "line5"),
    RegisterData(vValueL: "line6"),
    RegisterData(vValueL: "line7"),
    RegisterData(vValueL: "line8")
]

func compressData(elements: [RegisterData]) -> [RegistrationInformation]{
    var regDatas : [RegistrationInformation] = []
    for i in 0..<elements.count {
        if i != (elements.count-1){
            regDatas.append(RegistrationInformation(leftTitle: regData[i].vValueL, rightTitle: regData[i+1].vValueL))
        }else{
            regDatas.append(RegistrationInformation(leftTitle: regData[i].vValueL, rightTitle: ""))
        }
    }
    return regDatas
}

print(compressData(elements: regData))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do, would something like this help:

```
let regDatas: [RegistrationInformation] = zip(0...3, 4...7)
    .map { left, right in
        RegistrationInformation(leftTitle: String(left), rightTitle: String(right))
}
```

or even:

```
let regDatas: [RegistrationInformation] = (0...3).map { 
    RegistrationInformation(leftTitle: String($0), rightTitle: String($0 + 4))
}
```