# How would I create a function that takes an array and returns a two dimensions array?

Tags: arrays, swift, function, multidimensional-array

I am having problems creating a function that accepts an array and returns a two-dimensional array. An an example like [1,2,3,4,5,6] = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]].

So far I only have :

```
       func spiltArray(numbers:[Int])->[[Int]]{

  }
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/40841663/3141234

Answer (score -1):

```
func spiltArray(numbers:[Int])->[[Int]]{
    var result:[[Int]] = []
    if numbers.count == 0{
        return result
    }
    let split = 2
    var arr:[Int] = []
    for item in numbers{
        if(arr.count>=split){
            result.append(arr)
            arr = []
        }
        arr.append(item)
    }
    result.append(arr)
    return result
}
```