# how to access the next element in array without index running out of range?

Tags: swift

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5]
 

for i in 0..<a.count {
    print(a[i+1])
}
```

// How can I make sure it doesn't run the for loop if the next element in the array
// doesn't exist ?

Comment: I could do it by adding if   &&a[I != last , ,  is there a better way ?

Comment: If you're using +1 as the index, subtract 1 from the count.

Comment: You may also use a guard statement before print and compare to nil and if it fails you may exit the loop

Comment: So I assume you want to access both `a[i]` and `a[i + 1]` in each iteration? Otherwise you could just drop the first element and loop over the resulting array slice.

Comment: maybe just add a condition before print if `i + 1 > a.count - 1 {return}`.

Comment: Does his answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/40841663/3141234

Comment: `for i in a.indices.dropFirst() {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways. Which one you should take depends on your intent.

```swift
a.dropFirst().forEach {
  print($0)
}
```

```swift
import Algorithms

for pair in a.adjacentPairs() {
  print(pair.1)
}
```

https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/AdjacentPairs.md